# ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.3.min.js:8 Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

My application works fine until i had install ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.3.min.js

i inject ui.bootstrap as dependency

```
var app = angular.module("earnfitApp", ['ngRoute','ui.bootstrap']);
```

i include the js file also

```
        <!-- ================== BEGIN BASE JS ================== -->
            <script src="assets/plugins/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
            <script src="assets/plugins/jquery/jquery-migrate-1.1.0.min.js"></script>


<script src="assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/ngStorage.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/EarnfitApp.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/controllers.js"></script>
```

but as i hit to my local server it gives a blank white page. and as i open the console it shows some error as follow

```
ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.3.min.js:8 Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
angular.js:4640 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module earnfitApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ui.bootstrap due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ui.bootstrap' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/nomod?p0=ui.bootstrap
    at http://localhost:2000/earnfitangular/angular/assets/js/angular.js:68:12
    at http://localhost:2000/earnfitangular/angular/assets/js/angular.js:2082:17
    at ensure (http://localhost:2000/earnfitangular/angular/assets/js/angular.js:2006:38)
    at module (http://localhost:2000/earnfitangular/angular/assets/js/angular.js:2080:14)
    at http://localhost:2000/earnfitangular/angular/assets/js/angular.js:4617:22
    at forEach (http://localhost:2000/earnfitangular/angular/assets/js/angular.js:321:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:2000/earnfitangular/angular/assets/js/angular.js:4601:5)
    at http://localhost:2000/earnfitangular/angular/assets/js/angular.js:4618:40
    at forEach (http://localhost:2000/earnfitangular/angular/assets/js/angular.js:321:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:2000/earnfitangular/angular/assets/js/angular.js:4601:5)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=ui.bootstrap&p1=Err…st%3A2000%2Fearnfitangular%2Fangular%2Fassets%2Fjs%2Fangular.js%3A4601%3A5)
    at http://localhost:2000/earnfitangular/angular/assets/js/angular.js:68:12
    at http://localhost:2000/earnfitangular/angular/assets/js/angular.js:4640:15
    at forEach (http://localhost:2000/earnfitangular/angular/assets/js/angular.js:321:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:2000/earnfitangular/angular/assets/js/angular.js:4601:5)
    at http://localhost:2000/earnfitangular/angular/assets/js/angular.js:4618:40
    at forEach (http://localhost:2000/earnfitangular/angular/assets/js/angular.js:321:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:2000/earnfitangular/angular/assets/js/angular.js:4601:5)
    at createInjector (http://localhost:2000/earnfitangular/angular/assets/js/angular.js:4523:19)
    at doBootstrap (http://localhost:2000/earnfitangular/angular/assets/js/angular.js:1758:20)
    at bootstrap (http://localhost:2000/earnfitangular/angular/assets/js/angular.js:1779:12)
```

i not understand what i did wrong, any help is appreciable.

Comment: Have you added angular js ?

Comment: @SurenSrapyan yes suresh i had, application worked before adding ui.bootstrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reorder your script references like this.

```
<script src="assets/js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/EarnfitApp.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/controllers.js"></script>
```

It errored because bootstrap ui was not referenced before your app.js

Answer (score 0):

i noticed that you did not include angularjs on html

```
<!-- ================== BEGIN BASE JS ================== -->
<!-- Include angularjs here-->
<script src="assets/path/to/angularjs/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/jquery/jquery-migrate-1.1.0.min.js"> </script>
<script src="assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.3.min.js"></script>
```